# Validate specific date format in C#

Tags: c#, date, validation

The following string needs to be validated: `"04-01-2021 00:00:00 +00:00"`.

I've got the following method that checks if a string is a valid date, although it returns false for this string.

```
        private static bool IsValidDate(string value)
        {
            var allowedFormats = new[]
            {
                "yyyy-MM-dd", "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                "dd-MM-yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyyTHH:mm:ss", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
            };
            var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-GB");

            return DateTime.TryParseExact(value, allowedFormats, cultureInfo, 
                DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, out _);
        }
```

Is there anything I'm missing from the `allowedFormats`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work with `"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss zzzzz"` format string.

`zzzzz` part stands for offset (`+00:00`) in your string.

Check out the [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/locale/time-formatting-and-time-zones-in-dotnet-framework).